# Link for 'Show all Events Categories'

Tags: plugins, plugin-event-organiser

I expect this is a silly question but could you please tell me, what is the link to 'show all categories' in the event organiser plugin By Stephen Harris. Sorry to be daft.

Comment: Since @stephenharris is active here, hopefully he'll see the question and can help you out. :)

Comment: Hi Paddy - can you explain what you mean by 'show all categories'. Do you mean a link to a page listing events in all categories?